# Using web services to create a meeting; need to generate a uid

Tags: web-services, guid

What are the guidelines around generating a uid for the Meetings.AddMeeting web service call if I am not using C#? I am actually making the call from iOS/android.

Would any random string of numbers/letters with the dashes work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating UUID/GUID is defined by [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). The description and an example to generate them is shown here - [Generate GUID Online](http://www.somacon.com/p113.php) (in PHP but can be translated to other languages).

Comment: The generated GUIDs on that page look to be of type 1, i.e. they are based on the time and system they are run on. There is a link at the bottom to another online generator that allows you to generate type 4 (random) GUIDs.

Comment: I think the PHP example generates Type 4 (as per the link page) and defined by RFC 4122 4.4. Type 1 uses time stamps & clock as defined RFC 4122 4.2.2. The RFC 4122 (link above) describes the types and also includes sample 'C' code to generate the GUID.

Comment: Right, though when you compare the GUIDs generated on the first page with the type 1 GUIDs on the second page, (at least for me) they are very similar. Site 1: E6DE9E60-B71E-11E1-BD36-C20D6288709B, site 2: f00a3c10-b71e-11e1-afa6-0800200c9a66. Note the B71E-11E1 parts that are in common.

Comment: that is not the (PHP) link I mentioned above.. apparently the other link (http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen) has obviously some issues since the middle segments repeats itself!

Comment: Thank you; it is more complicated than I thought, but luckily I do happen to be familiar with PHP.  I will post iOS code when I implement this.